# Issue with Running C Programs in Visual Studio Code: Missing or Non-executable .exe Files

Tags: c

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI8iI.png)

vs code is not running any c programs it give me that there is no .exe file and even for the old codes I had they are not working saying that the exe file are not on executable format and I am unable to find the solution I try to reinstall it and reinstall the mingw. I had the mingw32 but then I reinstall a newer one but this happens after the problem was shown.